# apache response very slow even there is few W in server status

Tags: apache, performance, loading

I am facing a strange situation with apache. Frequently it is getting very slow even with a simple php page that calls `phpinfo()`.
While monitoring server-status of apache, it is slow when there is appear few "W" server-status. Like:

```
Current Time: Tuesday, 05-Sep-2017 17:21:27 NPT
Restart Time: Tuesday, 05-Sep-2017 16:56:13 NPT
Parent Server Generation: 1
Server uptime: 25 minutes 14 seconds
Total accesses: 488 - Total Traffic: 92.7 MB
CPU Usage: u.03 s.1 cu0 cs0 - .00859% CPU load
.322 requests/sec - 62.7 kB/second - 194.6 kB/request
5 requests currently being processed, 15 idle workers

_____W___W__L_W____W............................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
```

With above server-status, even server-status page loading very slow.
It is slow in local network (LAN).

What is a likely cause of this performance problem?